# how to print cvs content in ordered form in django template

Tags: python, django

here is my django app...
it print csv content in django template but not in organised form..(see output)..

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pandas as pd

def index(req):
    df = pd.read_csv("Users\Documents\data\myproject\datanalysis\PastHires.csv")
    f=df.head()
    return render(req,'index.html', {'content':f}) 

<html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{{content}}
</body>
</html>

OUTPUT
Years Experience Employed? Previous employers Level of Education \ 0 10 Y 4 BS 1 0 N 0 BS 2 7 N 6 BS 3 2 Y 1 MS 4 20 N 2 PhD Top-tier school Interned Hired 0 N N Y 1 Y Y Y 2 N N N 3 Y N Y 4 Y N N
```

but i want like this in my django template

```
Years Experience Employed?  Previous employers Level of Education  \
0                10         Y                   4                 BS
1                 0         N                   0                 BS
2                 7         N                   6                 BS
3                 2         Y                   1                 MS
4                20         N                   2                PhD

  Top-tier school Interned Hired
0               N        N     Y
1               Y        Y     Y
2               N        N     N
3               Y        N     Y
4               Y        N     N
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your content within a table, take a look at the examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

```html
<body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Years of Experience</th>
        <th>Employment Status</th>
        <th>Previous Employers</th>
        <th>Level of Education</th>
      </tr>
      {% for data in f %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{data.experience}}</td>
        <td>{{data.employment}}</td>
        <td>{{data.previous}}</td>
        <td>{{data.education}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: not working ...thanks for responding my question @t0bi

Comment: You have to define in your template how you want to present your data (header, body, table, chart, etc). So, in order to format the data on your webpage, include your HTML code in the template file at "myproject/datanalysis/templates/datanalysis/index.html".

Comment: do you have any examples so that i can take a reference from that..@t0bi

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/04/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-1.html) to get you started with Django. Then, the link in my answer contains everything you need to know about adding a HTML table to your webpage.